# Streaming data from local serial port to off site web server (and back?)

Tags: ssh, communication, data-transfer

In my project I have a teensy 3.1 reading and decoding NMEA strings coming in from an EM-406 GPS module. That data, after being decoded, is sent over serial through an xbee into my computer where I can then read the data out in my terminal. Now this is all well and good and I am sure some cool projects can be made, but I want to go further.

After the data is coming into my computers serial port, I want to pipe it into my web server so I can have my GPS data interact with the Google maps javascript API. The only issue I am having is figuring out how to get a constant stream of data from my local machine into my server.

I know about rsync and scp and tools like that, but those don't seem like the right fit since (to my knowledge) they work on updating and/or moving files around. In contrast, I need something that will have a consistent open connection that I can freely send data through, like a network serial port (is that a thing and I just answered my own question?).

I am assuming I can use ssh in this situation but I am not sure how to approach that. Does anyone have any suggested reading or an idea that could give me a nudge in the right direction?

Comment: I don't know any software for that. But what you describe should work e.g. via some (permanent) SSH Tunnel, so you might want to check for that.

Comment: Ever heard of WebSocket?

Comment: If the network you are talking about is an internal one (not the internet), you can look at the `socat` command which streams data over a network or between serial and network.

Comment: It is over the network, but of my approach in this is to teach myself about network communication, it's never going away so mine as well try and understand it. I fell towards the idea of sockets though, they really seem like what I am looking for

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would suggest a [python](http://www.python.org) script with the [pyserial](https://pythonhosted.org/pyserial/) and possibly the [requests](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/) libraries although there are plenty of web interfacing libraries in the standard libaries.

All of the above are Free, gratis & Open Source and cross platform so should work on anything.

You can have one [thread](https://docs.python.org/2/library/threading.html) listening to the serial port and assembling transactions into complete ones and a second connecting to your web server via http post messages, *if that is what is is expecting*, to send the complete, *possibly reformatted or otherwise processed,* transactions to the server.  If the server is expecting a file upload or just about anything else you will be able to do that as well.

There are also a number of python libraries for direct use of the Google Maps API.

Comment: Yea that is pretty much exactly what I am looking for. I did stumble onto pyserial and have already starting reading up on it. I figured I would let the flow of the code dictate how I want to manage processing data, if it makes sense one way over another then I'll go down that rabbit whole

Answer (score 0):

Well, this solution is obviously not exactly what you are looking for, but it streams the serial dataflow to the network http://www.serial-com-port.com/
You may work with any serial port you have over your local (LAN) or IP network.